# event.stopPropagation works once jQuery automcomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I have jQuery automcomplete widgets on a popup form.  And an event handler on the body element that if you click outside the popup form, to close the popup but if in the popup, use event.stopPropagation so the form does not close.  If you clicked on an item in an autocomplete dropdown, the popup was closing, so I added event.stopPropagation to the select: inside the autocomplete.  That works, but only once.  If use a dropdown a second time, and click a value, the popup closes.

I renamed some variables, so apologize for anything inconsistent, you should get the gist.

From some browser debugging, it looks like select function is not fired after the first time, so like stopPropagation kills it.

body element event handler:

```
$("body").on("click", function(e){
    clearPopupNew();
    unloadPopupNew();
});
```

popup div event handler to prevent above handler from running:

```
// the popup form
$("#popup_b").on("click", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

autocomplete code:

```
$("#status").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,        
    source: function( request, response ) {

        $.getJSON("/ajax/getstatus.json", request, function( data, status, xhr) {
            response(data);
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }     
});
```

Comment: Rails 4? Using turbolinks?

Comment: Hi, no, on Rails 3 on this app. Thx.